# Dynamically create React Routes Using Data From Component State

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am trying to dynamically create routes using react-router-dom. The route will depend on the id of a state I have in one of my components. How can I achieve this?
App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Categories}></Route>
        <Route path="/:cat" component={Recipes}></Route>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Categories.js which I want to get the id (:cat) from - the state categories has an id value:

```
class Categories extends React.Component {
    state = {
        categories: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/categories/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({categories: data});
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            
        );
    }
}
```

I have seen others use useParams but I can't do that since Categories is a class.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: A `<Route path="/:cat" component={Recipes} />` is all you need to create a dynamic route. Are you really trying to ask a different question, like how to then navigate to a dynamic route? You're correct, the `useParams` hook can't be used in a class component, but it also isn't used to generate routes, it gives you the currently matched route's `match.params`. Please clarify what you are trying to do and what, if any, issue is.

Comment: So the 'categories' state has an 'id' property to it. What I want to do is create multiple routes using the ids from categories. Ex/ categories = [id=4]. I want the route to be "/4". If categories=[id=8], the route should be "/8".

Comment: `path="/:cat"` handles that. The ":cat" is a "placeholder" for the actual value of the path, i.e. if you navigate to "/4" then in the route `match.params.cat` will be `"4"`. Does this make sense? Also, `categories = [id=4]` isn't valid array syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

*this.props.match.params*

i.e:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>R</p>
      <BrowserRouter>
       <Switch>
        <Route path="/categories/:id" component={Recipes}></Route>
        <Route path="/" component={Categories}></Route>
       </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

class Categories extends React.Component {
  state = {
    categories: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/categories/')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({categories: data});
        });
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.categories.map((c) => (
          <div>CAT: {c.name}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Recipes extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  componentDidMount() {
     console.log('Params:',this.props.match.params)
  }

  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes more sense now.